# Circular traversing in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

Is there any way to traverse the DOM in a circle? Like, when you get to the end of the list, it loops back around to the beginning?

Here's an example, which does not work, but will hopefully illustrate the effect I would like to achieve:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="four"></li>
</ul>

$('li.four').next().addClass('one');
```

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004593/how-jquery-data-breaks-circular-reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but you can trivially write your own method;

```
jQuery.fn.nextOrFirst = function (selector) {
    var next = this.next.apply(this, arguments);

    if (!next.length) {
        var siblings = this.siblings();

        if (selector) {
            siblings = siblings.filter(selector);
        }

        next = siblings.first();
    }

    return next;
};
```

Then use like (http://jsfiddle.net/sszRN/);

```
$('li.four').nextOrFirst().addClass('one');
```

Comment: Just what I was in the process of typing :)

Comment: In case anybody is curious, this function can be rewritten to traverse the opposite direction simply by changing next -> prev, and first -> last. I called it prevOrLast. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use

```
var $next = $( $(this).next()[0] || $(this).prevAll().addBack()[0] );
```

yeah, crazy :D

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking or trying to achieve here but if you merely want to add a class to the first element you can do this

Traverse the dom to find the parent element

Find the first child of that element - like this

`$('li.four').parent().find(">:first-child").addClass('one');`